# SP2013 online : set_formDigestHandlingEnabled Error

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, office-365

I get the error :

> Object doesn't support property or method 'set_formDigestHandlingEnabled'

when I try to get the current `SPContext` object from javascript code in an Office 365 site.

I am using a script editor web part and getting the context to do further operations

```
var cntxt;
.
.
.
cntxt = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
```

Has anyone faced this before?

Comment: Have you tried `cntxt = new SP.ClientContext(currentUrl);`?

Comment: I have tried that. Doesn't work !!

Comment: Are you making the call from an app or a regular site collection on your O365 host?

Comment: Not an app. I have just placed a script editor web part on my page in an Office 365 site collection. If I try to get the "SP" and "SP.ClientContext" objects in the IE developer toolbar console, the objects are returned.. It is just the "get_current()" method that is throwing the error !!

Comment: Try removing all other custom scripts from the page, and then calling SP.ClientContext.get_current() in the console; does this happen on just this page, or others, just this site collection, or others?

Comment: Thanks John. That actually helped me drill down the issue. I tried getting the SP.ClientContext.get_current() on one of the OOB page (documents all items page) and it works. I have other scripts on the page that i get the error. Something is wrong with that. I also get the erro "Object doesn't support property or method 'customFromJson'".   Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments to the original question, the way in which the scripts are loaded on your page must be preventing SharePoint from initializing all of the standard JavaScript items on the page. Add your custom scripts one by one, and remember that you may need to use jQuery.ready, `SP.SOD.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(<yourscript>, "SP.js") // or sp.ui, or sp.core, or something else, but usually SP.js is sufficient`, or some other similar technique to make sure SharePoint has initialized its environment before you load your custom script.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error message in a html without SharePoint Server rendering. For me I mixed up the load sequence of the sp.runtime.js and sp.js. You have to load the sp.runtime.js before the sp.js

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
  <script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
  <script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
```

Comment: this helped.....

Answer (score 5):

Using 'new' is definitely required, as suggested by wjervis: `var context = new SP.ClientContext(currentUrl);`

Comment: Adding 'new' worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded function :

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(internalOpenDialog, "SP.JS");

function internalOpenDialog(){
......
//code
....
}
```