# Simple clientContext.get_current throws undefined error

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I have just started developing with Sharepoint Add-ins. I'm using the JavaScript API. Find below my code:

```
'use strict';

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getAllFiles, "sp.js");
//SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', helloWorld);
function getAllFiles() {
    try {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        //var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("Number:" + e.number + " and Description:" + e.description);
    }
    alert("Client context retrieved");
}
```

I get both the alerts from above code. One from catch block and the latter one outside the catch block. The one generated from catch block doesn't give any error number or error descritpion. All it gives is `

> "Number:undefined and description:undefined"

`

Comment: Why have you stopped using the `Sp.SOD.executeFunc`? It is a better method to use than `ExecuteOrDelay...`, especially on MDS enabled sites

Comment: Yes, using SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getAllFiles); now. But still no success.

Comment: Just for some added information, I'm running this on <tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<developer_site>/. In project properties, SiteUrl property has https protocol. Anything else I need to add to this piece of information?

Comment: maybe it's too early to get the context at this point of time?

Comment: If it's a addin, have you loaded the SP.Runtime.js file too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the new keyword

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

should be

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

Comment: Removing the new keyword didn't work for me.

Comment: The exception object does not have number and description properties try to print the message property instead alert(e.message); @sidnc86

Comment: Thanks that helped! I got a message saying "this.set_formDigestHandlingEnabled is not a function". I searched for it and got my answer on this StackExchange question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110211/sp2013-online-set-formdigesthandlingenabled-error. I had to include sp.runtime.js and that too before sp.js. Doing so prevented the exception being thrown.

Comment: I too got the error `this.set_formDigestHandlingEnabled is not a function`. Turns out I had *forgotten* to add the new keyword.