# loading workflowservice manager from javascript giving "Invalid request" error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow, javascript

I have a web part page where a list view is added and need to start workflows on items in this list using java script, on click of a button.
Below is the code snippet, which fails with error message

> "invalid Request"

.

```
Response
    [
    {
"SchemaVersion":"15.0.0.0","LibraryVersion":"16.0.5228.1203","ErrorInfo":{
"ErrorMessage":"Invalid request.","ErrorValue":null,"TraceCorrelationId":"c8fa7c9d-10e8-3000-0a9b-5db5f926b721"
,"ErrorCode":-1,"ErrorTypeName":"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
},"TraceCorrelationId":"c8fa7c9d-10e8-3000-0a9b-5db5f926b721"
}
]
```

Code:

```
function SendStatusEmail()
{
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";    
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function () {
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function () {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.WorkflowServices.js", function () {
            StartWorkflow();
        })
    })
});
}

function StartWorkflow() {

var listGuid = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
JSRequest.EnsureSetup()
var itemId = JSRequest.QueryString['ID'];
var workflowName = 'WFsendemail';
var initiationParameters = null
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Contract_Status');
var item = list.getItemById(itemId);

clientContext.load(web);
clientContext.load(list);
clientContext.load(item);

var servicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(clientContext, web);
clientContext.load(servicesManager);
var subs = servicesManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().enumerateSubscriptionsByList(listGuid);
clientContext.load(subs);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var subsEnum = subs.getEnumerator();
    var workflowSub;

    while (subsEnum.moveNext()) {
        var sub = subsEnum.get_current();
        var subName = sub.get_name();

        if (subName == workflowName) {
            workflowSub = sub;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (workflowSub) {
        console.log('Web: ' + web.get_url() + ', Subscription: ' + workflowSub.get_name() + ', id: ' + workflowSub.get_id());

        var initiationParams = initiationParameters || {};
        servicesManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(workflowSub, itemId, initiationParams);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
            console.log('Workflow started.');
        }, Function.createDelegate(this, logError));

        callback();
    }
    else {
        logError(this, {
            get_message: function () {
                return 'Can not find the workflow:' + workflowName;
            }
        });
    }
}, Function.createDelegate(this, logError));

function logError(sender, args) {
    // Log error to console
    console.log(args.get_message());

    // Handle Errors
};
};

function callback() {
console.log("callback executed");
}
```

Same code is used on Edit item form and its working.
Need help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with ClientContext object.
It was not loading properly. 
Initially error was : "invalid Request".

On next day it started showing below error( :O )

"Object doesn't support property or method 'set_formDigestHandlingEnabled'  "

After googling this error, I found that SP.Runtime.js and SP.js files were not loaded in sequence.
I had to load SP.Runtime.js before SP.js

reference link:[SP2013 online : set_formDigestHandlingEnabled Error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110211/sp2013-online-set-formdigesthandlingenabled-error)